# RecyclerView как включить fastscroll?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Есть `RecyclerView` и большой список. Необходимо включить быструю прокрутку списка, как на `ListView`. Вычитал, что необходимо использовать библиотеки 26 версии, в которых `app:fastScrollEnabled` поддерживается. Решил проверить:

```
...
compileSdkVersion 26
...
minSdkVersion 15
targetSdkVersion 26
...
dependencies {
...
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:26.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:26.1.0'
...
```

добавляю RecyclerView:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/rv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"
    app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_thumb"
    app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/fast_scroll_track"/>
```

Добавил все необходимые ресурсы и пробую запустить приложение на планшете с API 15, но прокрутки вообще нет. добавляю `android:scrollbars="vertical"` появляется индикатор прокрутки, но я не могу переместить ползунок.

Может я что-то упустил?

**UPD:** Оказывается при большом количестве элементов ползунок становится ничтожных размеров, и его невозможно увидеть. Разбираюсь как сделать его фиксированного размера.

**UPD-2:**
Прикрепить к ползунку статическую картинку не удается. Приложение попросту вылетает.

Попытка задать

```
<size
android:height="30dp"
android:width="30dp"/>
```

приводит лишь к увеличению ширины бегунка, высота остается ничтожно малой, чтобы заметить или нажать на него

Comment: Может `ThumbDrawable` описать с конкретными размерами?

Comment: @woesss не могу найти информации как это сделать.

Comment: Есть предположение переопределить этот метод [RecyclerView.LayoutManager.computeVerticalScrollExtent(RecyclerView.State)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.LayoutManager.html#computeVerticalScrollExtent%28android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.State%29) - судя по описанию, он должен вычислять размер вертикального ползунка