# Изменить размер ползунка fastScroll у RecyclerView

Tags: android

Подскажите пожалуйста, как задать минимальную высоту ползунка у fastScroll, так как когда много Item, она становится маленькой и не юзабельной..

Использовался встроенный fastScroll у RecyclerView (26+ версия)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/countryList"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
    app:fastScrollHorizontalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"
    app:fastScrollVerticalThumbDrawable="@drawable/thumb_drawable"
    app:fastScrollVerticalTrackDrawable="@drawable/line_drawable"

    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
```

На фото 1000 строк, видно что пользоваться таким скроллом невозможно, нужно хотя бы минимум 50 dp по высоте сделать..

[image: fastScroll]

Comment: [вот мой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/777487). я так и не разобрался как это сделать, в итоге попросту отключил эту возможность, и сделал фильтрацию содержимого.